# Tikzpicture: Steplike function

Tags: tikz-pgf

that code works almost fine. What I'm missing is a way to connect the lines in a way that it looks like a steps ...

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    xmin=0, xmax=6,
                    ymin=0, ymax=6,
                    xlabel={$t$},
                    ylabel={$\rho$},
                    axis y line=middle,
                    axis x line=middle,
                ]
                \addplot [black,domain=0:1, no marks] {6};
                \addplot [black,domain=1:2, no marks] {5};  
                \addplot [black,domain=2:3, no marks] {4};
                \addplot [black,domain=3:4, no marks] {3};
                \addplot [black,domain=4:5, no marks] {2};
                \addplot [black,domain=5:6, no marks] {1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[some text]   {some text}
        \label{fig:someLabel}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: and sorry for that code style ...

Answer (score 4):

Like this? Pgfplots documentation, section 4.5.3

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    xmin=0, xmax=6,
                    ymin=0, ymax=6,
                    xlabel={$t$},
                    ylabel={$\rho$},
                    axis y line=middle,
                    axis x line=middle,
                ]
                \addplot [black,const plot, no marks] coordinates {(0,6) (1,5) (2,4) (3,3) (4,2) (5,1)};
%                \addplot [black,domain=1:2, no marks] {5};  
%                \addplot [black,domain=2:3, no marks] {4};
%                \addplot [black,domain=3:4, no marks] {3};
%                \addplot [black,domain=4:5, no marks] {2};
%                \addplot [black,domain=5:6, no marks] {1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[some text]   {some text}
        \label{fig:someLabel}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```